# Was sind die korrekten Fälle im Fall "in einer Art von"

Tags: declension

Eigentlich dachte ich, ich wüsste es, aber je länger ich schaue und analysiere, desto unsicherer werde ich: Zuerst hieß es "Ich befinde mich in einer Art professionellem Arbeitsverhältnis." Der Dativ "professionellem" schien mir dann aber unangemessen, denn eigentlich steht ja lediglich "Art" im Dativ (wegen "in einer"). "Ich befinde mich in einer Art professionelles Arbeitsverhältnis." (weil in "eine Art ..." folgt ja häufig ein Nominativ, oder?) liest sich aber richtig falsch. Am zufriedensten bin ich bisher damit "eine Art" zu deklinieren (Dativ) auf "eine Art" einen Genitiv folgen zu lassen "Ich befinde mich in einer Art professionellen Arbeitsverhältnisses."... aber ist *das* korrekt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die Verwendung von "eine Art ..." wird z.B. [hier](https://www.wortbedeutung.info/eine_Art/) beschrieben, und zwar so, dass nach "eine Art" ein substantivischer Ausdruck im selben Kasus folgt, in dem auch das "eine Art" steht.

> Ich befinde mich in einer Art professionellem Arbeitsverhältnis. (Dativ)
> Manche sehen in ihm eine Art politischen Sektierer. (Akkusativ)
> Ich selbst bin auch eine Art (dilettierender) Wissenschaftler. (Nominativ)
> Von ihm war immer die Rede als einer Art Sprechers der Clique. (Genitiv)

Natürlich gibt es auch die Verwendung mit "eine Art von", die immer mit Dativ steht.

> Sie hielt ihn offenbar für eine Art von unfehlbarem Super-Experten.
> Sie hielt ihn offenbar für eine Art unfehlbaren Super-Experten.

Den Genitivus partitivus würde ich nicht benutzen, aber mein Eindruck ist, dass sich zumindest für manche Fälle auch das verbreitet, vielleicht in Anlehnung an andere Gebräuche des Wortes "Art" mit Genitiv.

> Er servierte eine Suppe nach Art eines Erbseneintopfs.
> => Die Suppe war eine Art pürierten Erbseneintopfs.

Grammatisch nicht völlig falsch, aber ich würde es so nicht sagen.

Comment: Dass dein verlinkter Artikel "eine Art ..." als "umgangssprachlich" markiert, halte ich für diskussionswürdig. Wiktionary z.B. tut das nicht (versteckt dafür diese Verwendung in den Fußnoten).

Answer (score 2):

Kurz: Kommt drauf an, was du für dein Objekt hältst.

Es könnte sein: "Eine Art professionelles Arbeitsverhältnis" (alles im Nominativ) - das ist ganz einfach ein Nominalausdruck, so wie "eine Art Hund".

Oder es könnte sein "Eine Art professionellen Arbeitsverhältnisses". Das ist der Versuch eines partitiven Genitivs, der im Deutschen in gehobener Sprache typischerweise für Stoffanteile (Getränke,...) gebräuchlich ist ("ein Glas sauren Weines"). Für andere Anteile wie in deinem Beispiel sieht man den noch viel seltener, er ist sehr ungebräuchlich und definitiv am Veralten. (Versuch' mal, "eine Art Hund" mit einem partitiven Genitiv auszudrücken, das ergibt leider keinen - zumindestens für mich -  akzeptablen Satz).

Ich würde sagen dein erstes Beispiel (kompletter Nominalausdruck im Dativ) ist vollkommen richtig, das Beispiel mit partitivem Genitiv *eigentlich* auch, aber sehr "geschraubt".